# QSlider with a custom stylesheet to make pressed handle bigger

Tags: stylesheet, pyside, handle, qslider

i want to make a material like slider. The slider handle should get bigger when pressed, but when I click on it, it makes this:
[top: not clicked, bottom: klicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb6Aq.jpg)
And after I move the handle its getting bigger.
I'm using a stylesheet:

```
...
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: #009ceb;
    width: 24px;
    margin: -12px 0; 
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #009ceb;
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal:pressed{
background: #009ceb;
width: 36px;
margin: -18px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 18px;
border-width: 1px;
}
...
```